# How to pass Response from one controller to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, httpresponse

//clientjobdescriptionscontroller.cs

```
[HttpGet]
        public void Download(string format, string requests)
        {
            List<string> req = requests.Split(',').ToList();
            foreach (var item in req)
            {
                RequestController controller = new RequestController();
                if (format == "I")
                {
                    Response.Write("rakesh");
                    controller.DownloadrequirementsInternalUse(Convert.ToInt64(item));
                }
                if (format == "R")
                {
                    controller.DownloadrequirementsRecruitmentPartner(Convert.ToInt64(item));
                }
                if (format == "CA")
                {
                    controller.DownloadrequirementsCandidate(Convert.ToInt64(item));
                }
                if (format == "CR")
                {
                    controller.Downloadrequirementscustomer(Convert.ToInt64(item));
                }
            }
        }
```

// RequestController

```
 public void DownloadrequirementsInternalUse(long Id)
        {
            var result = requestService.GetResourceAvailability(Id);

            JobDescriptionPdfDownload jobDescriptionPdfDownload = new JobDescriptionPdfDownload();
            string strOutput = jobDescriptionPdfDownload.DownloadrequirementsInternalUse(Id);

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=JD-Internal-Use-" + result.RequestCode + ".pdf");

            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            CreatePdf(strOutput);
        }
```

Comment: Your controllers should return `ActionResult` and then you can use them like ordinary class methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use action method (return actionresult) in your controllers and  try this

```
return RedirectToAction("DownloadrequirementsInternalUse", "RequestController", new {  id=Convert.ToInt64(item) });
```

Comment: It is not letting the controller to the mentioned action.
    return RedirectToAction("DownloadrequirementsInternalUse", "RequestController", new { Id = Convert.ToInt64(item) });

Comment: you must set the two method in both controller to retruen action result .

Comment: Sorry But I did not get your answer.
Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I mean you must have two action controller on your both controllers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use your action method like this

public ActionResult Download(string format, string requests)
{

}
```

Comment: Tried but it is not being run.

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Download(string format, string requests)
        {
            List<string> req = requests.Split(',').ToList();
            foreach (var item in req)
            {
                RequestController controller = new RequestController();
                if (format == "I")
                {
                    //Response.Write("rakesh");
                    return RedirectToAction("DownloadrequirementsInternalUse", "RequestController", new { Id = Convert.ToInt64(item) });                 
                }
}
}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.